# Python while loop counter ignores limit

Tags: python, while-loop, count

I am new to stackoverflow so I apologise if I have not formatted my code correctly. In my hangman game, the while loop is supposed to stop when count==0. However, it stops when count=-2. What have I done wrong and how can I solve it?
Thanks!

```
word = 'hello'
dict1 = {}
import time

def words(words):
  count = len(words) + 3
  lines = []
  for i in words:
      lines.append('_')

  print('It is a', len(word), 'letter word\n',
      'You have ', count, 'guesses!')
  time.sleep(1)
  print('The first word is: ', words[0])
  while count > 0:
      for i in words:
          count -= 1
          time.sleep(1)
          answer = input('please input a letter')
          if answer=='':
              print('This is incorrect. You have ',count,' goes left')
          elif answer == '{}'.format(answer) in word:
              dict1.setdefault(answer, 0)
              dict1[answer] = dict1[answer] + 1
              for k, v in dict1.items():
                  if dict1[answer] > 1:
                      print('No duplicates! You have ', count, 'goes left')
                  else:
                      for i in range(0, len(word)):
                          if word[i] == answer:
                              lines[i] = answer
                      print( '\n Well done! You have ', count, 'goes left!')
              hangwords = ''.join(map(str, lines))
              print(hangwords)
              if hangwords == words:
                  print('You have won! You had', count, 'goes left!')
                  return hangwords

          else:
            print('This is incorrect! You have', count, 'goes left')

  if count==0:
      print('You have failed. The word was '+word)
      exit()

print(words(word))
```

Comment: you have another loop inside the while loop, the while loop condition `count>0` won't be checked until the inner loop is done, that's probably why it gets to -2 before terminating

Comment: You use function as an iterator, and with the same name as variable, in little code like this one this is not a problem (well, in fact it is), but in larger code, you well quickly be overwhelmed. By the way, is this normal that your code output several time the text `Well done!...` ? Maybe a bit a reshaping and cleaning will help you understand your errors by your own.

Comment: @AdrienKaczmarek Hi, sorry that was my error when putting the code in stack. Thank you for the feedback about the function names, I'll look to change it

Answer (score 0):

a) use `break` and not `exit()`
b) the if statement needs to be inside the for loop. as you have it now, it is checked after the for loop and it already got below 0 while the for loop is running

Answer (score 0):

You have a two layer loop going on, that's causing the issue.

Check out your word to guess : "hello". It's length is 5.
You have set the limit to 8.
The loop is running 10 time & does not have any if conditions or a break statement.

8 - 10 = -2.